# How to extend PHP with C++?

Tags: php, c++, extension-methods

Can I write a C++ code that can be compiled and used for extending PHP (I don't mean calling an executable file)? Can I describe some classes, functions and use them for in my PHP code by calling the compiled (.so or .a file) C++ code? If yes, then please explain me schematically how it is being done.

Comment: very interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063490/how-to-extend-tcl-with-c

Comment: Yes, TCL and PHP are for very wide range, but sometimes they are too slow. This solves C++. So the combination of these 2-3 programming laguages give a REAL POWER!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do so by writing a PHP extension.
See [PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide to the Zend Engine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php).

Answer (score 2):

The Zend engine is a good option as already mentioned in the previous answer.

Other alternative is SWIG (it supports multiple languages)

Specifically, for php with C++, you can refer to:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html